# How to delete rows by calling its row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have this data stored in the SQL Server

[image]

How can I delete the first three rows by calling the row number found in the left (1,2,3)?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. That row number is not tangible and is nothing more than the order the results were returned in. SQL does not guarantee order of data, so there is no rule that says if you run the same query 20 times, you'll get the same results at 1,2, and 3 each time. That's not to say you won't get them same results, they're just not guaranteed. You need to delete using a column that actually exists as part of the table definition, such as F1, F2, etc...

As others have suggested in the comments, try to clean up the data before you import it into SQL Sever. You have a few options.

1. Delete the rows from the file before importing.
2. Configure the Import Wizard correctly to exclude those rows.

**Helpful link**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Oh I see, I am stuck to this and I can't find the answer on other sites, so this is why. So its like I need to modify this first by deleting the first three rows before importing it to the database. Thank you for this.

Comment: Are there not columns you can use to delete the rows you want to delete?

Comment: What stands out in those top three rows that makes you want to delete them?

Comment: The data actually starts from the 4th row and it should be my column names. This is from a CSV file imported to SQL Server, but I guess I'll just have to delete it in the CSV file itself.

Comment: @ArmandoBridena - Yes, modify the spreadsheet before importing. Also, if you're using the SSMS import wizard, check the box titled "First Row Has Column Names" so your the table has columns named "CountryName,CountryCode,..." instead of "F1,F2,...."  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Right, but in terms of what is in the database. For example WHERE F1 IN ('Data Source','Last Updated Date') OR F1 IS NULL. That looks like what you're looking for here.

Comment: @ArmandoBridena - What tool are you using to import the file? (Edit) BTW, I totally agree with Brendan is saying from a database POV. Just mentioning options to use on the Import Wizard side.

Comment: Looks like you are importing some CSV/excel file. You can check this answer on how to skip them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417724/skipping-rows-when-importing-excel-into-sql-using-ssis-2008

Comment: Okay okay, I will look into this